# how to left-align cells with the FixedDataTable library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fixed-data-table

I am trying to left-align cell values in my FixedDataTable implementation. Below is the code I am using:

```
require('./app.css');
require('fixed-data-table/dist/fixed-data-table.min.css');
const     $ = require('jquery');
const React = require('react');

import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';



const App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
                <Table
                    height       = {200}   width     = {200}
                    rowsCount    = { 10}   rowHeight = { 26}
                    headerHeight = {100}>
                    <Column
                        width={100}
                        cell={props=>(<Cell className='align-right'>{props.rowIndex}</Cell>)}
                        align='left'
                        header="Right-aligned values"/>
                    <Column
                        width={100}
                        cell={props=>(<Cell className='align-left'>{2*props.rowIndex}</Cell>)}
                        align='left'
                        header="Left-aligned values"/>
                </Table>
        );
    }
});

export default App;
```

And the css file I `require` is simply:

```
.align-right {
    align: right;
    text-align: right;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.align-left {
    align: left;
    text-align: left;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

What I get is the following:

[image]

... which demonstrates that the styles are indeed applied, except for the alignment part.

Inspecting the various elements (of type `div` mostly) that `FixedDataTable` creates in the DOM it appears that my class is assigned at a level too deep to matter (the enclosing div is already left-aligned).

Comment: You want to right align the left column? If that's the case, why is `align='left'` for both the `Column`s.

Comment: Same as @Kujira, you set it to align='left'

Comment: @Kujira you are referring to the `align` attribute of the `Column` - this is just the alignment of the *header*, not of the cells. Even if I set it to 'right', sure enough the *header* is aligned right but the cells remain aligned left.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus I haven't played around with it, but according to the docs, [align: The horizontal alignment of the table cell content](https://facebook.github.io/fixed-data-table/api-column.html).